# Function Module to copy purchase order to another order

Tags: bapi, sap-erp

I'm creating documents using the function module `BAPI_PO_CREATE1` and modifying documents using `BAPI_PO_CHANGE` to update some parts of the purchase order.

I need to create two orders with the same purchase order lines, one for purchasing and another for transferring.

I can do it calling `BAPI_PO_CREATE1` twice with the same `POITEM`s. Is there a function module to create a copy of a purchase order using a reference number (`PO_NUMBER`) and a modified header?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use BAPI_PO_CREATE1 using fields PREQ_NO and PREQ_ITEM from POITEM structure.
Just ensure you have update structure POITEMX with these fields...

Try it out and let me know.